# Filling an array concurrently

Tags: swift, memory, memory-management, grand-central-dispatch, swift5

I am stumbling upon an issue with concurrency and arrays in Swift 5. To reproduce the issue I have simplified my code to the following fragment:

```
import Dispatch

let group = DispatchGroup()
let queue = DispatchQueue(
  label: "Concurrent threads",
  qos: .userInitiated,
  attributes: .concurrent
)

let threadCount = 4
let size = 1_000
var pixels = [SIMD3<Float>](
  repeating: .init(repeating: 0),
  count: threadCount*size
)

for thread in 0..<threadCount {
  queue.async(group: group) {
    for number in thread*size ..< (thread+1)*size {
      let floating = Float(number)
      pixels[number] = SIMD3<Float>(floating, floating, floating)
    }
  }
}

print("waiting")
group.wait()
print("Finished")
```

When I execute this in debug mode using Xcode Version 10.2 beta 4 (10P107d) it always crashes with an error like:

```
Multithread(15095,0x700008d63000) malloc: *** error for object 0x104812200: pointer being freed was not allocated
Multithread(15095,0x700008d63000) malloc: *** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
```

I have the feeling that this is some bug in the compiler because when I run the code in release mode it runs just fine. Or am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: I'd be really suspicious of writing to the `pixels` array from multiple threads concurrently.

Comment: Indeed, and running that code with the Thread Sanitizer enabled triggers a “WARNING: ThreadSanitizer: Swift access race” instantly. I cannot reproduce the malloc error though.

Comment: OK, but I do not intend to access any item in the array concurrently. So how can I solve this? The different threads access different non overlapping parts of the array. I just want to fill different parts of the array at the same time.

Comment: Can you explain why my code would generate a program that frees a pointer that was not allocated?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are pointers inside an Array that absolutely can change under your feet. It is not raw memory.

Arrays are not thread-safe. Arrays are value types, which means that they support copy-on-write in a thread-safe way (so you can freely pass an array to another thread, and if it is copied there, that is ok), but you can't mutate the same array on multiple threads. An Array is not a C buffer. It's not promised to have contiguous memory. It's not even promised to allocate memory at all. Array could choose internally to store "I'm currently all zeros" as a special state and just return 0 for every subscript. (It doesn't, but it's allowed to.)

For this specific problem, you'd typically use vDSP methods like vDSP_vramp, but I understand this is just an example, and there may not be a vDSP method that solves the problem. Typically, though, I'd still focus on Accelerate/SIMD methods rather than dispatching to queues.

But if you are going to dispatch to queues, you'll need an UnsafeMutableBuffer to take control of the memory (and ensure that the memory even exists):

```
pixels.withUnsafeMutableBufferPointer { pixelsPtr in
    DispatchQueue.concurrentPerform(iterations: threadCount) { thread in
        for number in thread*size ..< (thread+1)*size {
            let floating = Float(number)
            pixelsPtr[number] = SIMD3(floating, floating, floating)
        }
    }
}
```

The "Unsafe" indicates that it's now your problem to make sure all the accesses are legal and that you're not creating race conditions.

Note the use of `.concurrentPerform` here. As @user3441734 reminds us, `pixelsPtr` is not promised to be valid once `.withUnsafeMutablePointer` completes. `.concurrentPerform` is guaranteed not to return until all blocks are complete, so the pointer is guaranteed to be valid.

This could be done with DispatchGroup as well, but the `.wait` would need to be inside of `withUnsafeMutableBufferPointer`.

Comment: sorry the SIMD3 was a typo from my part

Comment: You are not really allowed to modify the pointer inside of withUnsafeMutableBufferPointer (the method verifies on return that the pointer still has the same value). The pointer is inout so that you can call mutating methods on it (like sort), compare  https://forums.swift.org/t/se-0245-add-an-array-initializer-with-access-to-uninitialized-storage/21469/10

Comment: @MartinR I thought you could actually do a full replacement of the underlying buffer. Thanks for the link correcting that.

Comment: Even though this could work without any trouble, this approach is very dependent on the current implementation but it doesn't guarantee it is really thread-safe.  I suggest using a more conservative approach, split required data first, process data chunks in parallel and finally join them back. This will guarantee the job to be done the same way, independent from implementation details, with a minimal performance penalty.

Comment: @user3441734 I'm not quite certain what you mean here about being dependent on the current implementation. `withUnsafeMutableBufferPointer` is intended to (and documented to) give direct access to the array's mutable contiguous storage. This is all defined behavior. What implementation concern do you have? Joining large arrays together can be very expensive; I'm not sure why you say "with a minimal performance penalty" if `size` were, for example, 100 million (consider processing a 21600x21600 BlueMarble image).

Comment: @RobNapier withUnsafeMutableBufferPointer must first make a continues storage (there is no guarantie it exists). than it should be copied "thread" times, because all of the "thread" use a differnet copy for processing, so where is the advatage? maybe I don't understand it ...

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "a different copy." `withUnsafeMutableBufferPointer` is only called one time, and it will ensure contiguous storage in one go (in practice, it's almost certainly already contiguous storage). The only thing that's copied is the pointer, not the buffer.

Comment: @RobNapier I understand your point of view, what I am tallking about is (from apple docs)"The pointer passed as an argument to body is valid only during the execution of withUnsafeMutableBufferPointer(_:). Do not store or return the pointer for later use." In other words, there is no guarantie, that while executing the async closure, it is (or will be in the future implementation) still valid. That is my point of view.

Comment: @user3441734 You're making a really important point, but it's not about the implementation details. It's about the lifetime of the pointer. And you're 100% correct that it is not promised after the block has returned. This particular case does get the promise because of the DispatchGroup, but I agree that the DispatchGroup is sloppy (this was bothering me before, and it was your comment that brought it into focus). Using `DispatchQueue.concurrentPerform` here would give you a more correct promise. (I'd rewritten the code that way earlier, but it didn't seem worth the edit until your comment.)

Comment: pixels.withUnsafeMutableBufferPointer { (bp) -> Void in
    DispatchQueue.concurrentPerform(iterations: workers, execute: { (worker) in
        for n in worker*size ..< (worker+1)*size {
            bp[n] = worker
        }
    })
} . It llooks a little bit better, the beffer poiner is valid until it finnished,  But it is? I am not very sure. .concurentPerform is my favorite in general :-) I am using it almost everywhere :-). In reality is the same ... unfortanetly.

Comment: @user3441734 Why aren't you sure? The pointer is valid until `withUnsafeMutableBufferPointer` finishes, and that can't finish until `concurrentPerform` finishes. Are you saying that it's impossible in Swift to perform concurrent work on a single block of memory because there are no memory guarantees? (that's not true)

Comment: @RobNapier see previous lines ... The only way I see, is to aalocate the buffer, use it and dealocate "manualy".

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190317/discussion-between-user3441734-and-rob-napier).