struct in swift is thread-safety, Array is struct, why Array is not thread-safety?
@frozen public struct Array<Element> {

This is the declaration of Array in swift. struct in swift is thread-safety, Array is struct, why Array is not thread-safety?
First, I declare a struct.
struct MyStruct {
    var testArray: [Int] = [1]
｝

Then, I write a concurrent test, It crashed when running
var test = MyStruct ()
DispatchQueue.concurrentPerform(iterations: 500) { index in
    test.testArray.append (100) //Thread 14: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, a...
｝


Possibly helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/q/75459511/1187415

"struct in swift is thread-safety" is generally not true. Where did you read that from?
